# Plotly: different symbols on scatterplots

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(plyr)

df <- data.frame(
    Category = c('foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo'),
    x = c(2.1, 3.4, 4, 4),
    y = c(16, 21, 10, 17)
)

palette <- c("#007700", "#cc0000")
fig <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~x, y = ~y, size = 10, color = ~Category,
               colors = palette)
fig
```

How would I get the `foo` points to plot as squares and the `bar` points as triangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `symbol=~Category` and define `symbols=`:

```r
plotly::plot_ly(
  data = df, x = ~x, y = ~y, size = 10, color = ~Category, colors = palette,
  symbol = ~Category, symbols = c(15, 17)
)
```

[image: plotly with squares and triangles]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where the list of all the pre-made symbols is? (15 = solid square, 17 = solid triangle, etc.)

Comment: Honestly, I look it up each time I can't remember them: https://www.google.com/search?q="r"+"plot"+"pch". (Plotly accepts the base R symbols.)